# Elastix Hyla FAX Says No Local Dial Tone

Tags: asterisk, elastix

I have an Elastix Server configured Virtual FAX with IAX extension 123. When I am trying to send a FAX it shows "No local Dial Tone". Please anybody help me.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check you have iax modems started and registered at asterisk

2) check you have configured virtual fax with same device id

3) if not help, check asterisk console.

Comment: When I am running **/usr/sbin/iaxmodem iaxmodem-cfg.ttyIAX1**
`[..] Modem started
[..] Setting device = '/dev/ttyIAX1'
[..] Setting owner = 'uucp:uucp'Setting mode = '660'
[..] Setting port = 40000
[..] Setting refresh = 300
[..] Setting server = '127.0.0.1'
[..] Setting peername = '123'
[..] Setting secret = 'aabbcc'
[..] Setting cidname = 'faxtest'
[..] Setting cidnumber = '8487703'
[..] Setting codec = ulaw
[..] Opened pty, slave device: /dev/pts/3
[..] Created /dev/ttyIAX1 symbolic link
[..] **Registration failed.**`
Please help me.

Comment: so what you can't translate? registration failed. it is clear.

Comment: I want to know why the registration getting failed? --Thanks

Comment: Can you please suggest any books?

Comment: orelly's "Asterisk the future of telephony"